# NameError in PostsController#pingback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

This is my first time trying to get a Gem to work in rails where I haven't just been able to follow the documentation.

I first installed the gem using `sudo gem install ping back` and then added it to my Gemfile via `gem 'pingback'`. I then ran bundle install and it shows it installed in the list it outputs.

So then I wrong a little function that looks like this and is in my posts controller:

```
def send_trackback(posts)
  posts.each do |post|
    source_uri = "http://example.com/posts/#{post.slug_url}"
    target_uri = post.target_url
    Pingback::Client.new.ping(source_uri, target_uri)
  end
end
```

whenever I try to load the admin page that sends the trackbacks I get the following:

`NameError in PostsController#pingback`

`uninitialized constant PostsController::Pingback`

Do I have to do more than just install the gem via bundler and then plug and play?

***Update***

adding `require 'pingback'` to the top of my posts controller results in this:

`cannot load such file -- pingback`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted the rails server and I believe this has resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error message to me indicates that the VM is trying to find `PingBack` in `PostsController`, I am thinking you are missing a require or include statement for `PingBack`.

Comment: Can I just include it in the controller? or is there a better place to include it?

Comment: yeah, I don't see a reason not too.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a typo, but pingback needs to be one word, not 'ping back' for the line in the gemfile, and for the gem install.

I would try running 'bundle list' to make sure the gem is installed.

Comment: Thanks. That was a typo caused by autocorrect. `bundle install` results in me getting `* pingback (1.1.0)` which shows it is installed.